# How to send two querystring properties to the URL in jQuery load()

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass two variables to php using the jQuery `load()` function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$('#display').load('example.php?para1=' + para1 + 'para2' + para2);
```

Comment: `$('#display').load('example.php?para1=' + para1 + '&para2=' + para2);`

Comment: Yes, isn't this typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to send with object:

```
$('#display').load('example.php', {para1:para1, para2:para2});
```

From the docs of `.load()` method second argument in the `.load()` method is an object to send additional data to the server.

> #### .load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )
>
> **Description**:
>   Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.
>
> **url**
>   Type: String
>   A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
>
> **data**
>   Type: PlainObject or String
>   A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.
>
> **complete**
>   Type: Function( String responseText, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
>   A callback function that is executed when the request completes.